# Nested JSON data into Datatable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, laravel, datatables

So I have a pretty long (nested) JSON array (I've minified it):

```
      {
  "items" : [ {
    "track" : {
      "album" : {
        "name" : "Pressure Makes Diamonds"
      },
      "artists" : [ {
        "name" : "Danny Vera"
      } ],
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/7rO7Pc5dkC2EIW1OKsCJtQ",
      "name" : "Roller Coaster"
    }
  }, {
    "track" : {
      "album" : {
        "name" : "Amigo"
      },
      "artists" : [ {
        "name" : "Chef'Special"
      } ],
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/6yvxKrf9KZLTodXFTBmdR1",
      "name" : "Nicotine"
    }
  }, {
    "track" : {
      "album" : {
        "name" : "Lines (New Version)"
      },
      "artists" : [ {
        "name" : "Niels Geusebroek"
      } ],
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/62En58kZelNGnGvmJUMVC0",
      "name" : "Take Your Time Girl (live at ruud de wild/538)"
    }
  } ]
}
```

and I'm trying to display it in a Datatable with this code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#table_id').DataTable( {
                processing: true,
                data: {!! $response !!}, // <= this is where the JSON comes from (Laravel)
                columns: [
                    { "track" : "name" },
                    { "track" : "album.name" },
                    { "track" : "artists[0].name" }
                ]
            })
        })
    </script>
```

Anyone got any idea what I'm doing wrong? 
I looked up the Datatables ([Datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep.html#:%7E:text=DataTables%20has%20the%20ability%20to,standard%20Javascript%20dotted%20object%20notation.)) and followed it, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Laravel has https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/installation try this

Comment: `"track"` is not a valid DataTables option for a column. I suspect you mean to use `"data"`, inside your `columns` section - possibly like this: `"data" : "track.album.name"`. See the example page [here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep). But for this to work, you also need the main `data` option `data: {!! $response !!}` to point to `"items"`, since that is the name of the array DataTables will be iterating over.

Answer (score 0):

Ait got it:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#table_id').DataTable( {
                processing: true,
                data: {!! $response !!}["items"],
                columns: [
                    { "data" : "track.name" },
                    { "data" : "track.album.name" },
                    { "data" : "track.artists[0].name" }
                ]
            })
        })
    </script>
```

Thanks yall!!